# Use induction: postage $\ge 64$ cents can be obtained using $5$ and $17$ cent stamps.

Tags: induction

I have come up with:

Assume for any $n\ge 64$ there exists numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $n = 17x + 5y$

and also then that $n+1 = 17x + 5y + 1$

but am fairly new to the concept of induction and not sure where to go after this.

Comment: $$n+1=17x+5y+(5\cdot7-2\cdot17)=17(x-2)+5(y+7)$$

Comment: I'm not clear on how you have reached this equation

Comment: @Derpm  (5*7 - 2*17) = 1, he knows that $5$ and $17$ are both relatively prime (in fact prime), so there exists a linear combination that adds to 1.

Comment: I see that now, my initial n+1 equation was wrong.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $x,y$ must be **nonnegative** integers, because you can't put a negative number of stamps on a letter. So your solution fails when $x=0$ or $x=1.$ (If $x$ and $y$ can be arbitrary integers, there is no need for the hypothesis $n\ge64.$)

Comment: $n$ needs to be $\ge 64$ so how can a solution be reached with non-negative integers?

Comment: $$64=17\cdot2+5\cdot6,65=17\cdot0+5\cdot13,66=17\cdot3+5\cdot3,67=17\cdot1+5\cdot10,68=17\cdot4+5\cdot0$$ $$69=17\cdot2+5\cdot7,70=17\cdot0+5\cdot14,71=17\cdot3+5\cdot4,72=17\cdot1+5\cdot11,73=17\cdot4+5\cdot1$$

Comment: Yes I have found those, or well, 64-68 as base cases. I am unclear how to carry on with the inductive phase.

Comment: Wait, the solution is determined first by what n is, so x and y couldn't be non negative right?

Answer (score 0):

You can exhibit combinations of stamps for $64,65,66,67$ and $68$ cents as your base case, and then use the inductive step of adding a $5$ cent stamp for any greater amount.

The inductive phase addresses values of $69$ cents or more and can assume that the previous $5$ lesser values all have valid combinations of stamps.

---

More explicitly:

Base case:

- $n=64$: $2\times$ $17$c stamps and $6\times$ $5$c stamps:
- $n=65$: *you can fill these in*
- $n=66$:
- $n=67$:
- $n=68$:

Inductive step: For any $k\ge 69$, assume that $n$ cents in the previous five values can be made by $a_n\times$ $17$c stamps and $b_n\times$ $5$c stamps.

Then for $k$ cent value set $a_k = a_{k-5}$ and $b_{k} = b_{k-5}+1$, giving:
$\begin{align}
17 a_k + 5 b_k &= 17a_{k-5} + 5(b_{k-5}+1)\\
 &= 17a_{k-5} + 5b_{k-5} + 5\\
 &= (k-5) + 5 = k\\
\end{align}$
as required

Comment: I'm not sure how to carry on with the inductive phase other than the way other solutions have shown

Comment: Added a more explicit inductive step.

Comment: This is the only correct solution that has been posted, the only one that doesn't miss the whole point. The downvote is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

1. Base step: Show that there are values of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy $17x+5y=64$.
2. Inductive step: Assume that there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $17x+5y=n$. Use that assumption to show that there must exist $x'$ and $y'$ such that $17x'+5y'=n+1$.

Checking the base step is important and I will leave that to you. For the inductive step, using $17x+5y=n$ we can re-write $n+1=17x+5y+1$. Then, use the hint given by lab bhattacharjee.

Comment: Right so I understand and have reached $n+1 = 17(x-2) + 5(y+7)$ in my own working- is this the proof (if so, how?) or do I need to find something further?

Comment: does it satisfy the question because it ends up being $17$cents x something and $5$cents x something which was what I needed to prove?

Comment: This solution is invalid because the problem requires that $x$ and $y$ are **nonnegative** integers.

Comment: Of course, if $x,y$ are only required to be integers, not necessarily nonnegative, there is no need for the hypothesis $n\ge64;$ **every** integer can be expressed in the form $17x+5y$ for some integers $x$ and $y.$

Answer (score 0):

Base case: show that it works for n = 64

17x + 5y = 64

$x = 2, y = 6$ [OK]

---

Inductive Step: supposing it works for $n$, prove it works for $n+1$

there must exist $x'$ and $y'$ such that:

$17x' + 5y' = n + 1$

using the hypothesis, we can say $n = 17x + 5y$

$17x' + 5y' = 17x + 5y + 1$

$17(x' - x) + 5(y' - y) = 1$

say $(x' - x) = a$ and $(y' - y) = b$

if there are $a$ and $b$ such that $17a + 5b = 1$, than there will exist satisfying $x'$ and $y'$.

$a = -2, \;b = 7 \implies 17(-2) + 5(7) = -34+35=1$

Then, as we know $x$ and $y$ exists by hypothesis, for $n+1$ you just need to use $x' = x - 2$ and $y' = y + 7$ and you will get it.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are required to be **nonnegative**.

Comment: How can the solution be reached then, where $x$ and $y$ are non-negative?

Comment: @Derpm See the correct solution by Joffan.

Comment: I think this is still correct. From what I know about induction it is an implication sort of situation, where if $n \ge 64$, then $n = 17x + 5y$ etc

Comment: From the induction hypothesis, even if $x,y$ are nonnegative, we can't be sure that $x'=x-2$ is nonnegative. And it's clear that the question is asking for nonnegative numbers. (1) Can't put negative number of stamps on a letter. (2) The assumption $n\ge64$ is irrelevant if arbitrary integers are permitted, but it's just what we need to get $x,y\ge0$, since $17x+5y=63$ has no solution in nonnegative integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can exhibit combinations of stamps for $64,65,66,67,..., 99$ cents as your base case, for instance, and then use the inductive step.

---

More explicitly:

Base case:

- $n=64$: $2\times$ $17$c stamps and $6\times$ $5$c stamps:
- $n=65$: *you can fill these in (with the help of a computer)*
- $n=66$:
- $n=67$:
- $\vdots$
- $n=99$:

Inductive step: For any $99\leq k\leq n$, assume that $$k=17a_k+5b_k,$$ to some  nonnegative integers $a_k$ and $b_k$.

Hence, $$n+1=17a_n+5b_n+1=17a_n+5b_n+(35-34)=17(a_n-2)+5(b_n+7).$$

If $a_n\geq 2$ the proof finishes.

Otherwise, note that $64\leq k=n+1-17\leq n$ and  $k=17a_k+5b_k$.

It follows that $$n+1=17(a_k+1)+5b_k,$$ for instance.

Comment: Based on @Joffan post.